# Flexbox CSS does not work in Featherlight Light Box. How else can I position elements within the Lightbox,or fix Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, featherlight.js

I am trying to position several elements in a centered column within a Featherlight Lightbox. Flexbox CSS seems to be getting overwritten by something in the lightbox's CSS so it refuses to work. Everything is just being placed in the default position to the left of the the light box.

Flex strikethrough:

[image: flex strikethrough]

I am still new to CSS, so playing with margins and padding isn't working for me to well. Either I manage to get the elements centered and there is excess white space on either side, or they don't position properly at all.

Is it possible to fix/force flexbox to work? Otherwise what other styling options do I have.

CSS:

```
<style>

    .logo{

    margin:auto;
    width:72px;
    height:72px;

    }
    .teamname{

    margin:auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .suburb{

    margin:auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .teaminfohead{

    margin:auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .teaminfo{

    margin:auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .teamphoto{

    margin:auto;

    }


    .lightbox {
    display: none;

    }

    .lightbox_active {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;

    }



    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1"data-featherlight-variant="lightbox_active">Open element in lightbox</a>
    <div class='lightbox' id='fl1'>

            <img class='logo' id='logo' src="images/PBS.png">
            <h1 class='teamname' id='teamname'></h1>
            <h2 class='suburb' id='suburb'></h2>
            <h3 class='teaminfohead' id='teaminfohead'></h3>
            <p class='teaminfo' id='teaminfo'></p>
            <img class='teamphoto'id="teamphoto" src="images/PBSteam.png">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add wrap into div lightbox

```css
.lightbox { display: none }
.lightbox__wrap {
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class='lightbox' id='fl1'>
<div class="lightbox__wrap">
  <img class='logo' id='logo' src="images/PBS.png">
  <h1 class='teamname' id='teamname'>ABC</h1>
  <h2 class='suburb' id='suburb'>CFG</h2>
  <h3 class='teaminfohead' id='teaminfohead'>jlasj dlak</h3>
  <p class='teaminfo' id='teaminfo'>j laskdj ald</p>
  <img class='teamphoto'id="teamphoto" src="images/PBSteam.png">
</div>
</div>


<a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1"data-featherlight-variant="lightbox_active">Open element in lightbox</a>
```